# How do I split a single row into multiple rows and Insert into a table in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

I select data from table `Employee_Master` using the below query

```
SELECT EMP_ID
, EMP_NAME
, EMP_LOC1
, EMP_LOC2
, EMP_LOC3
, EMP_DESG
, EMP_ADDR1
, EMP_ADDR2
, EMP_ADDR3
, EMP_PHNO
, EMP_STATUS
FROM Employee_Master
WHERE EMP_STATUS = 'A'
```

The Result set looks like this.

```
    EMP_ID          EMP_NAME         EMP_LOC1      EMP_LOC2    EMP_LOC3   EMP_DESG  EMP_ADDR1   EMP_ADDR2   EMP_ADDR3   EMP_PHNO    EMP_STATUS
     23       Covey, Stephen J, Mr       1            2            4       Writer       3         3            3          11          A
     24       Jhon, Abraham A, Mr        1            2            4       Actor        1         1            1          22          A
```

Now I have to split the one record into three records and insert in into `Emp_history` table like this. `EMP_SAL_ID` is fetched from a different table which I can take care of.

```
    EMP_SAL_ID  First_Name  Middle_Initial  Last_Name   Title   Designation Location    Address Phone_No    Status
       3456      Stephen          J           Covey      Mr       Writer       1           3        11         A
       3456      Stephen          J           Covey      Mr       Writer       2           3        11         A
       3456      Stephen          J           Covey      Mr       Writer       4           3        11         A
```

Is it possible to achieve this using PL/SQL block or any other simple method with performance.?

Comment: Please provide the create and insert statements. You could use **UNION** in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use **UNION** to have separate rows for each address value.

For example, let's say you have a row as built in the with clause:

```
SQL> WITH DATA(EMP_NAME,EMP_ADDR1,EMP_ADDR2,EMP_ADDR3) AS(
  2  SELECT 'Covey, Stephen J, Mr', 1, 2, 4 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  3  SELECT 'Jhon, Abraham A, Mr ', 1, 2, 4 FROM DUAL
  4  )
  5  SELECT * FROM DATA;

EMP_NAME              EMP_ADDR1  EMP_ADDR2  EMP_ADDR3
-------------------- ---------- ---------- ----------
Covey, Stephen J, Mr          1          2          4
Jhon, Abraham A, Mr           1          2          4

SQL>
```

Now you could split the above row into multiple rows using **UNION**. Just an additional effort is to use **SUBSTR** and **INSTR** to extract the name from emp_name.

For example,

```
SQL> WITH DATA(EMP_NAME,EMP_ADDR1,EMP_ADDR2,EMP_ADDR3) AS(
  2  SELECT 'Covey, Stephen J, Mr', 1, 2, 4 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  3  SELECT 'Jhon, Abraham A, Mr ', 1, 2, 4 FROM DUAL
  4  )
  5  SELECT SUBSTR(emp_name, instr(emp_name, ',', 1, 1)+1, instr(emp_name, ' ', 1, 2) - instr(emp_name, ',', 1, 1)) AS "ename",
  6    emp_addr1                                                                                                  AS "addr"
  7  FROM DATA
  8  UNION ALL
  9  SELECT SUBSTR(emp_name, instr(emp_name, ',', 1, 1)+1, instr(emp_name, ' ', 1, 2) - instr(emp_name, ',', 1, 1)),
 10    emp_addr2
 11  FROM DATA
 12  UNION ALL
 13  SELECT SUBSTR(emp_name, instr(emp_name, ',', 1, 1)+1, instr(emp_name, ' ', 1, 2) - instr(emp_name, ',', 1, 1)),
 14    emp_addr3
 15  FROM DATA
 16  /

ename                      addr
-------------------- ----------
 Stephen                      1
 Abraham                      1
 Stephen                      2
 Abraham                      2
 Stephen                      4
 Abraham                      4

6 rows selected.

SQL>
```

**NOTE** :

The **WITH** clause is only used to build sample data for demonstration purpose. In real case, you just need to use the **SELECT** statement on your table.

```
INSERT INTO hist_table SELECT statement as shown above...
```

Comment: So, Just like the example given by you, I select necessary columns and insert it using insert from select. is that correct?

Comment: @SqlNerd Yes exactly. `INSERT INTO hist_table SELECT...`

Answer (score 0):

```
create table adress_test(ename varchar2(30), addr number);


insert all 
   into adress_test values(SUBSTR(emp_name, instr(emp_name, ',', 1, 1)+1, instr(emp_name, ' ', 1, 2) - instr(emp_name, ',', 1, 1)), emp_addr1)
   into adress_test  values(SUBSTR(emp_name, instr(emp_name, ',', 1, 1)+1, instr(emp_name, ' ', 1, 2) - instr(emp_name, ',', 1, 1)),emp_addr2)
   into adress_test values(SUBSTR(emp_name, instr(emp_name, ',', 1, 1)+1, instr(emp_name, ' ', 1, 2) - instr(emp_name, ',', 1, 1)),emp_addr3)

   SELECT 'Covey, Stephen J, Mr' EMP_NAME , 1 EMP_ADDR1, 2 EMP_ADDR2, 4 EMP_ADDR3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Jhon, Abraham A, Mr ', 1, 2, 4 FROM DUAL
;
```

Answer (score 0):

As a variation on the answer from Lalit:

```
WITH DATA(EMP_NAME,EMP_ADDR1,EMP_ADDR2,EMP_ADDR3) AS(
  SELECT 'Covey, Stephen J, Mr', 1, 2, 4 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Jhon, Abraham A, Mr ', 1, 2, 4 FROM DUAL
 ),
 a as (select 1 as n from dual
     union all select 2 as n from dual 
     union all select 3 as n from dual)
 select emp_name, case a.n 
                  when 1 then emp_addr1 
                  when 2 then emp_addr2 
                  when 3 then emp_addr3 end as emp_addr
from data inner join a on 1=1
```

This might be more efficient for large tables. The big table (data) needs to scanned only once.